# PHP- get previous rows value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains the following:

```
ID | value
1  | Hello
14 | Potato
34 | Henry
```

The information is echoed using the following foreach:

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM table") as $X){
 echo $X['ID']; 
 echo $X['value']; }
```

Is there a way to get the ID from the previous row in the table as a variable?
So as the result looks something along the lines of this:

```
echo "Current ID: ".$X['ID'];
echo "Current value: ".$X['value'];
echo "Previous value: ".$PreviousValue;
```

gives

> Current ID: 14
>
> Current value: Potato
>
> Previous value: Hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use first
$previousValue = null;
```

then use this

```
if($previousValue) {
    echo $previousValue;
  }

$previousValue = $X;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of it from the previous fetch:

```
$prev = null;
while($row = ...) {
   ... do stuff with $row ...
   $prev = $row;
}
```